# Setting different values for build configurations in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, project-settings

I need to set different output paths for release and debug builds. But in new VS UI foldout field with build configurations for properties window disappeared, and now it's seemed to have different options for each field in properties. But for some reason options are locked for me.

[image]
[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: The GUI may not be able to show all possible settings you can do in the project file. You probably already have some custom settings in your project file, so you need to edit that directly.

Comment: So I did... I opened project file in txt

Comment: Then please edit the question and add the file. It could help to answer your question.